# Why my PrimeFaces's controls do not work after migration?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Just migrated from jboss 7.1 to wildfly 16 and PrimeFaces 4.0 to 6.2.

As I know PrimeFaces uses ajax with its elements such p:commandLink, p:commandButton, etc.

I have:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{exampleBean.redirrectSomewhere}">
     labelName
</p:commandLink>
```

After tapping at the commandLink nothing is happening, but if I add **ajax='false'** as an attribute, it is going to work fine.

Is there some way to get redirected using ajax?

Ask for extra information.

Comment: First thing as web developer would be to look in browser's JS console for any hints.

Comment: also using `p:link` is better for redirecting except you want to execute and the redirect for that return a string in that method that matches this pattern `urltofile?faces-redirect=true`

Comment: Sure this worked in PF 4? And [mcve] please

Comment: @BalusC
Found out the solution via looking in the browser's **Network** tab. It's said there was render error. 
Somehow happened that after migration js script has just broken.

Thank everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (at least to me). Use `process="@this"` to make sure that the ajax updates current component instead of the whole view. You can then remove `ajax="false"`.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. Adding `process=@this` to make it work mask another underlying issue like va;idation failures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value